# What is the origin of 'yes siree!'?

Tags: etymology

We all know it from cowboy films and the like but where does the 'siree' come from? Is it a deliberate mispronunciation of 'sire' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to wikipedia](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yessiree#English), it seems that it is derived, not from "yes *sire*", but from "yes *sir*". (Although both *sir* and *sire* themselves obviously come from the same roots.)

> Noun **siree** (uncountable)
>
> (slang) **Sir.** Used as an intensifier, emphatically, after yes or no.
>
> *e.g.*
>
> *"-Are you coming?"*
>
> *"-Yes, siree."*
>
> ([taken from wikipedia](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/siree#English))

It seems from Google N-grams that the phrase first came about in the late 19th century ([although this post suggests there it was used as early as 1846](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080312192845AAcVQTL)) Here is the N-gram, which includes all variants on spelling. (There is no *one* commonly-accepted spelling)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The OED explains that the *siree* element is a variant of *sorry*. That’s not the apologetic *sorry*, but a variant of *sirrah*, an earlier and pejorative term of address used to men and boys. The earliest recorded use of *yes siree* is dated 1846. *No siree* appeared a year earlier.

Comment: This is most interesting. Did "sir" come from the same source?

Comment: @J.R.: Yes. ‘Sirrah’ is a shortened form of ‘sir’, which ultimately derives from Latin 'senior'.

Answer (score 2):

The OED says of "yes siree":

> Etymology:  < yes adv. + *siree*, variant of sorry n.2

With an earliest quotation from 1846:

> ‘Will you take this man to be your lawful husband?’ said the Justice; to which she responded with breathless haste, ‘Yes, sir-ee’.

It says "no siree" came first:

> Etymology:  < no adv.2 + siree, variant of sorry n.2 Compare slightly later yes siree int.

With the first quote from 1845:

> Taint everybody that can put on the regimentalities, and look like old Mars, the god of war, with a decided touch of Julius Junius Ceaze... No, Sir-ee!

*Sorry* n.2 is from before 1555, a now regional and colloquial variant of *sirrah*:

> A familiar or (occas.) contemptuous form of address to a man or boy

*Sirrah* is now archaic, and dates back to 1526. *Sirray* and *sirrah* were both used by Shakespeare.